# Is there any way to enable global search for custom object without creating tab or without exposing tab to user

Tags: global-search, sales

I am trying to enable custom object in global search without creating tab. I think that is not possible.

http://cloud4good.com/announcements/best-practices-for-using-salesforce-global-search/

As per above blog post you can enable global search on custom object by creating tab but making it hidden. But that does not seems to solve my purpose because once I create a tab and make it hidden it gets removed from the list of elements where salesforce does global search. 
Has anyone worked around this problem. Thanks in advance for any pointers.